# Find the inverse of an operator, and determine is it bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I've been doing some similar problems, but I got stuck on this one... and I have a feeling I'm running in circles trying to solve it.

Any help appreciated!

**Problem:**

We have an operator:

$$ A : C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$$

$$ Ax(t) = x(t) + \int_0^1 e^{s+t}x(s)ds$$

Does $A^{-1}$ exist, and if so, is it bounded?

Comment: You can try to prove that $I-A$ is compact, then use Fredholm theory.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot!